# mysql distinct query returning more than 1 result

Tags: mysql, distinct

I'm expecting for one product along with it's title and due amount. this query however is not efficient. Not sure with what i'm missing here. Any help would be appreciated

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.product_title, po.qty, co.due_amount
FROM  pending_order po
LEFT JOIN products p ON p.product_id = po.product_id
LEFT JOIN customer_orders co ON po.invoice_no = co.invoice_no
LEFT JOIN customers cs ON cs.customer_id = co.customer_id
WHERE co.invoice_no = '1355021133'
```

the result i'm getting

[image]

Comment: Alternatively you can use GROUP BY

Comment: `DISTINCT` returns records which are distinct with regard to _all_ the columns you select.  If you want a single record back for each product title, then you'll have to aggregate and think about _which_ quantity and due amount you want to have for product title.